# Spring Integration Splitter and Aggregator : Release one by one

Tags: spring-integration

My requirement : incoming xml needs to be split into multiple nodes and each node has to be converted to json and send each node's json to http end point.

1. I could split the incoming json using XPathMessageSplitter
2. Collected all the messages at the Aggregator and converting it to json and right now i have `List<String>` .

Now i have to iterate the `List<String>` and send it to `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` one by one.

1. Is there any way to release the message one by one at aggregator side so that it will be to sent it to `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` outbound one by one?
2. or after receiving list of string at aggregator , any way to send it to `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` outbound one by one?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a simple splitter after the aggregator. The `DefaultMessageSplitter` (`<splitter/>`) will split any collection, iterable, iterator etc.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs @Gary. I will try this and come back

Comment: If you need `one by one`, I don't see reason to overhead with an aggregator in between. Looks like you are pretty fine just to deal with each splitted item directly.